# How to cast view to a custom layout in the onItemClick function of AdapterView.OnItemClickListener?

Tags: android

I'm new to Android. I want use a SimpleAdapter with a custom layout. Do I have store the original data and then use the `id` to access it? the `view` parameter should be something that I can use. But what is the proper way to do it?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_section);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MyListView);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
    {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("ItemTitle", "This is Title.....");
        map.put("ItemText", "This is text.....");
        mylist.add(map);
    }

    SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this,
            mylist,
            R.layout.list_delegate,
            new String[] {"ItemTitle", "ItemText"},
            new int[] {R.id.ItemTitle,R.id.ItemText});
    listView.setAdapter(mSchedule);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(TAG, "clicked: " + view);
        }
    });
}
//simplified activity_section.xml
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/MyListItem">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ItemTitle"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ItemText"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `findViewById` to access `ItemTitle` and `ItemText` from clicked row of ListView as:

```
String itemTitle = ((TextView) 
               view.findViewById(R.id.ItemTitle)).getText().toString();
```

Do same for accessing `ItemText` TextView value